# Set-Difference for strings and arrays

Tags: arrays, string, lisp, filtering, common-lisp

`set-difference` works as a filter function, but only for lists. What's about arrays and strings? Are there analogous functions for these types of data? If there are no such functions, what is the proper way to implement them?

For now I use this macro to process any sequence as a list (sometimes it's useful):

```
(defmacro treat-as-lists (vars &body body)
  (let ((type (gensym)))
    `(let ((,type (etypecase ,(car vars)
                    (string 'string)
                    (vector 'vector)
                    (list 'list)))
           ,@(mapcar (lambda (x) `(,x (coerce ,x 'list)))
                 vars))
       (coerce (progn ,@body) ,type))))
```

My `filter`:

```
(defun filter (what where &key key (test #'eql))
  (treat-as-lists (what where)
    (set-difference where what :key key :test test)))
```

Examples:

```
CL-USER> (filter "cat" "can you take this cat away?")
"n you ke his  wy?"
CL-USER> (filter #(0 1) #(1 5 0 1 9 8 3 0))
#(5 9 8 3)
```

Comment: There are not analogous functions in the standard for arrays and strings, but as you found out, you can define your own. Note that those coercions make the use of arrays and strings pointless.

Comment: I don't like the coercion to a list, since it involves a lot of consing just for being able to express the set-difference idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since writing functions that works on all sequences types often means writing separate versions for lists and vectors, it's worthwhile to use standard functions that operate on sequences where you can.  In this case, we can use [position](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm) and [remove-if](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm).  I've reversed the order of your arguments, in order to make this sequence-difference more like set-difference where the second argument is subtracted from the first.

```
(defun sequence-difference (seq1 seq2 &key (start1 0) end1 (start2 0) end2
                                           key (key1 key) (key2 key)
                                           test test-not)
  "Returns a new sequence of the same type of seq1 that contains the
elements of the subsequence of seq1 designated by start1 and end1, and
in the same order, except for those that appear in the subsequence of
seq2 designated by start2 and end2. Test and test-not are used in the
usual way to elements produced by applying key1 (which defaults to
key) to elements from seq1 and by applying key2 (which defaults to
key) to elements from seq2."
  (flet ((in-seq2 (x)
           (not (null (position x seq2
                                :start start2 :end end2
                                :key key2
                                :test test :test-not test-not)))))
    (remove-if #'in-seq2 
               (subseq seq1 start1 end1)
               :key key1)))
```

```
(sequence-difference "can you take this cat away?" #(#\c #\a #\t))
;=> "n you ke his  wy?"

(sequence-difference "can you take this cat away?" #(#\c #\a #\t) :start1 3 :start2 1)
" you ke his c wy?"
```

Note that the standard also includes [find](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_find_.htm#find), which works on arbitrary sequences, but find returns "an element of the sequence, or nil."  This leads to ambiguity if nil is a member of the sequence.  Position, on the other hand, returns either an index (which will be a number, and thus not nil) or null, so we can reliably determine whether an element is a in sequence.

There is one important difference here in that you're always getting a copy back here.  The reason for that is subjective:  Since sequence functions often take start and end index arguments, it's nice to include that functionality here.  But, if we ask for `(sequence-difference "foobar" "boa" :start1 2)` then we want to remove the characters b, o, and a from the "foobar"'s subsequence "obar".  What should we return though?  "for" or "r"?  That is, do we include the portion of seq1 that's outside the indices?  In this solution, I've made the decision not to, and thus I'm doing `(remove-if … (subseq seq1 …) …)`, and subseq always makes a copy.  Set-difference, on the other hand, may return its list-1 or list-2 argument, if appropriate.  This implementation generally won't return seq1 or seq2, except in some pathological cases (e.g., the empty list).

Comment: If `seq2` gets big enough (more than a few tens of elements), it might be worthwhile to preprocess it and use a better scaling inner function.  This optimization should be implemented depending on the length of the argument (but don't go too far in lists...).

Comment: That's a good point.  I think that some implementations of things like remove-duplicates and set-difference will actually create a hash of the elements in the subtrahend.  That only works when test is one of the four standard hash tests, but it would cover the default case.   Remove-duplicates could at least cut down on the linear search time.